# Pause script execution on window reload

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

I need to pause script execution in Chrome devtools as soon as possible, more specifically at the moment when no scripts are evaluated yet, or when `head` scripts are evaluated but `body` scripts are not.

In Node.js, there's an option to start devtools paused, but in a browser script execution is always resumed by default.

Currently I have to find a suitable random script in Sources tab and place a breakpoint at the beginning, usually it's possible but not guaranteed.

The question primarily applies to Chrome devtools but could be also applicable to Firefox.

How can script execution be automatically paused in devtools every time a window is reloaded?

Comment: Add `debugger` statement at the beginning of the code

Comment: I do this where necessary, but it's often code I don't have control over.

Comment: Devtools -> Sources -> Event listener breakpoints -> Script -> Script first statement, then reload.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, missed this event. Should be the answer then, feel free to post it.

Comment: Maybe some of the [old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Script+first+statement%22) can fit?

Comment: Sure. Much easier to find when you know the answer